# Why does saving a presentation to a file-like object produce a blank presentation?

Tags: python-pptx

As a response to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46980767/1868136) to a previous question of mine, I wrote the following short program to try and reproduce the problem.

```
from pptx import Presentation
from io import BytesIO

p = Presentation()
slide = p.slides.add_slide(p.slide_layouts[0])
slide.shapes[0].text = 'asdf'

p.save('test.pptx')

out = BytesIO()
p.save(out)

out_file = open('bytes_test.pptx', 'wb', buffering=0)
out_file.write(out.read())
out_file.close()
```

This produced two pptx files.

The first, test.pptx, contained a single slide with the "Title Slide" layout and containing the string "asdf". The file size was 28 KB.

The second, bytes_test.pptx, when opened in PowerPoint, showed only a large grey box that said "Click to add first slide". The file size was 0.

Running on Windows 10 with Anaconda Python 3.6.1 and python-pptx 0.6.6

Why does this happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, a couple things I can think of, this might take some back-and-forth.

First, I would try using `out.getvalue()` instead of `out.read()`. That's how I've always done it and its documented behavior is to get the entire contents of the stream.

If that doesn't work, I would add `out.flush()` and `out.seek(0)` before the `out.read()` call. `BytesIO` is a buffered output stream, and its possible some buffered data isn't getting written to the stream before the `read()` call. Also, I expect `read()` works from the current cursor position, which the `seek(0)` call would reset to the beginning of the file.

Let us know how you go with that and we'll take it from there.

Comment: Switching to getvalue() worked. However, the issue now becomes the fact that the original application I was writing this for doesn't read the BytesIO object itself, but instead passes it to Flask's send_file method. I'll have to look around the Flask documentation a bit more to see what my options are. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelPlante I expect it's looking for a sequence of bytes (binary string). In Python 3 I expect you can just pass it `bytes = out.getvalue()` and it will be happy. You may also need to pass it the MIME-type for a PowerPoint presentation ('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation') in order to get the desired download behavior.

Comment: Turned out that calling seek(0) and then passing the BytesIO to flask was enough.